# React Redux does not catch dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been struggling with this for couple hours and I can't find a solution
As I press the button, function "getLocation" is being called (Checked it)
But dispatch is not passed to reducer
From similar threads I found out that it might be because getLocation is a function and props value is set as function. Is there any way to call this function or any other possibility to make dispatch call store?
Below is my code:

*actions/geolocationAction.js*

```
export function getLocation() {
    const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
    return dispatch =>
        geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => 
        {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_LOCATION,
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
             });
        });
}
```

*Location Button*

```
class LocationButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick = { this.props.locationReceived } >Geo</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    locationReceived: () => dispatch(getLocation())
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LocationButton);
```

*geolocationReducer*

```
const geolocationReducer  = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default geolocationReducer;
```

and reducer *index*

```
export default combineReducers({
   location: geolocationReducer
});
```

If you could give me any tip how to solve this problem I would be really thankful

Comment: do a `console.log(action)` at `geolocationReducer`, right before `switch` statement. see what it's printing

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you don't check [`geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) error callback. Try returning a blank thunk that doesn't use `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and simply returns a dispatch with some sample data. If this works, include a callback for the error argument, and dispatch an action such as `GET_LOCATION_ERROR`, with the error that was passed.